# Mysql - SELECT Parent-Child with SORT

Tags: mysql, database, select, sql-order-by, parent

I have one level parent child relation table, with following columns:

`ID| Parent_ID | ProductTitle`

I need output grouped by Parent followed by children, and also sorted by Parent and Children Name.

I found a working example for SQL Server, but I need something that works on MYSQL. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48bab28f42327d41d11df9c6795c18a8

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.ID_Asset, 
       t1.Parent_ID_Asset, 
       t1.ProductTitle
FROM Test t1
LEFT JOIN Test t2 ON t2.ID_Asset = t1.Parent_ID_Asset
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.ProductTitle, t1.ProductTitle), 
         t1.Parent_ID_Asset IS NOT NULL, 
         t1.ProductTitle
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a0b353e9e5ebd34d83a672ffee5088e8

Comment: can it be done without left join as in the example?

Comment: @ninka436 I think that the answer is "Yes".

Comment: Do you know how to do it? :)

Comment: For MySQL 5.7? I will not do this - the solution will be complex, I'm too lazy for this.

Comment: Or do you have any clue? What should I use? I have a real example that is much more extensive - and I'm sitting on it for the third day. I don't seem any closer to a solution than three days ago ...

Comment: If you want to use only one table copy then you'd use user-defined variables accompanied with custom rows ordering. Also the data must have some characteristic which allows to perform such ordering (for example, each child's `id` must be greater than its parent `id`). This solution will be slow because it will perform iterative table scanning.

Comment: so i thought this might be the only way. Thank you for your help :)